# Problem with sending an object to the Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am creating a simple web project using Spring. I have two tables in my database: Recipe and Category. Each recipe is assigned to one category. I have a page where I have a list of my categoris and after clicking on one of them I am going to a page containing a list of recipies belong to this category. Under the list, I have a button to add a new recipe to the category. My problem is that I cannot assign a category_id to a recipe object in a form. Now I am sending to the controller a recipe that has category_id = null. When I debugged my code I get a proper category in the method ***addForm()***.

Here is my code:

class Recipe

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column (unique = true)
    private String name;
    private int time;
    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;
    @Column(length = 1024)
    private  String ingredients;
    @Column(length = 1024)
    private String instructions;



    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
    }

    public void setIngredients(String ingredients) {
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }

    public String getInstructions() {
        return instructions;
    }

    public void setInstructions(String instructions) {
        this.instructions = instructions;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Recipe(String name, int time, Category category, String ingredients, String instructions) {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
        this.category = category;
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
        this.instructions = instructions;
    }

    public Recipe() {
    }
}
```

class Category:

```
@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private List <Recipe> recipes;

    public List<Recipe> getRecipes() {
        return recipes;
    }

    public void setRecipes(List<Recipe> recipes) {
        this.recipes = recipes;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Category(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Category() {
    }
}
```

code from the Controller class:

```
    @RequestMapping("/add")
public String addForm(Category category, Model model)
{
    //this category has a proper name and id
    model.addAttribute("category", category);
    model.addAttribute("recipe", new Recipe() );
    return  "addRecipe";
}

@RequestMapping("/save")
public String addRecipe( @ModelAttribute Recipe recipe )
{
    //here I have a recipe with category_id=null
    recipeRepository.save(recipe);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

and the html file

```
<form th:action = "@{/save}" th:object = "${recipe}" method="post">
<input type = "text" th:field = "*{name}" placeholder = "Name"><br>
<input type = "number" th:field = "*{time}" placeholder = "Time"><br>
<input type = "hidden" th:field = "*{category}" th:value = "${category.id}"><br>
<textarea rows = "10" th:field = "*{ingredients}" placeholder="Ingredients"></textarea><br>
<textarea rows = "10" th:field = "*{instructions}" placeholder="Instructions"></textarea><br>
<button type="submit">ADD</button>
```

Thank you very mauch for any help.

Comment: Maybe the th:field for category input hidden should be `*{category.id}`

Comment: I tried it but now, the recipe is adding to a category with a new id. (I have 4 categories in database, and the recipe is added to category with id=5).

Comment: Could you check in the generated html (by clicking view page source in the browser) which is the value of the category.id hidden field?

Comment: in page source i have: value=""

Comment: that means this `th:value = "${category.id}"` is evaluated to null or empty string. In `addForm` method set the category in the recipe before adding the recipe to the model, something like this `Recipe r = new Recipe(); r.setCategory(category); model.addAttribute("recipe", r);`

Comment: It works! Thank you!